# How can I delete the oldest directory in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am writing a backup programm, and I need to execute a bash command to delete the oldest directory in a specific directory.

I have found this command to [print the oldest directory](https://superuser.com/a/552606/2259):

```
find -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 1
```

And this command to delete a directory and all its content:

```
rm -rf [oldest directory name]
```

How can I combine between these two in order to delete the oldest folder?

Comment: `-type f` finds only *files*, not directories.

Comment: Do you mean the oldest among the direct subdirectories only, or also among the indirect subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any path (Thanks to @StéphaneChazelas for the [`head` trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206/3645)) and should be POSIX compatible (formatted for readability):

```
printf %q "$(
    find . -type d -printf "%T+ %p\0" |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    sort |
    head -n 1 |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    sed -e 's/^[^ ]\+ //')"
```

To actually remove the directory, replace `printf %q` with `rm -rf --`

Comment: after executing the first line the bash says `date_and_path command not found`

Comment: Not in Bash 4, if you copy the command verbatim. `date_and_path` is not a command, but a variable which you then use in the next line.

Comment: Is there other way to execute this command without using the var `date_and_path`? Something like: `rm -rf -- find . -type d -printf "%T+ %p\0" | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | sort | head -n 1 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'`

Comment: Done. You have to use a more complicated way to remove the datetime at the start in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when running this command in shell, I don't get any error, but it also doesn't delete any file. Any suggestions?

Comment: When executing your code using `rm -rf <CODE>` nothing happens. When I execute with `printf %q <CODE>` I get this: `./07-07-2014` where the file name is actually `07-07-2014`. I think the `./` is what disturbing the execution from work. Do you have any idea how to remove the `./` and if that is the reason it doesn't work?

Comment: No, `./` is correct. I have no idea what you're doing to make it fail.